# Тире между двумя репликами в кавычках

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация, диалог

В справочнике Лопатина (§ 137) говорится следующее:

> в) точка и тире ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими разным лицам
> и снабженными разными авторскими словами: *Проходя мимо, он сказал: «Не
> забудь купить билеты». — «Постараюсь», — ответила я*; если же в первой
> реплике имеются знаки восклицательный или вопросительный, точка
> опускается: *Проходя мимо, он крикнул: «Не унывай!» — «Постараюсь», —
> ответила я...*

Тем не менее я неоднократно встречал пропуск тире между репликами персонажей, заключёнными в кавычки, если каждая реплика снабжается "со своей стороны" (или разрывается) авторскими словами.

Примеры:

- > Тут они напряглись: «Это что еще
  > за мультфильм?» «Ну как, — говорю, — Ленин был очень веселый человек.
  > Сделаю смешное кино про Ленина — все обхохочутся». Они поняли, что
  > положат на стол партбилеты за такое кино *(Из интервью с А. Татарским)*;
- > Ведерникову так не хотелось ее огорчать, что заныло в груди.
  > «Послушай, — сказал он как можно проникновеннее, с облачной мягкостью
  > удерживая руку знаменитости, раскалившуюся буквально как уголь, —
  > послушай, дело в самой моей истории. В ней все не так, как кажется.
  > Во-первых, я не собирался спасать никакого ребенка, я просто
  > почувствовал, что вот сейчас смогу прыгнуть». «Конечно, ты мог
  > прыгнуть! — нетерпеливо перебила Кира. — Ты был спортсмен, кандидат в
  > мастера!» «Как-нибудь потом объясню», — смутился Ведерников *(О. Славникова "Прыжок в длину")*.

Вопрос: **почему? Есть ли основание в справочниках?**

P. S. Единственное место в справочниках, которое я нашёл, где говорилось бы о репликах в диалоге в кавычках, но без тире, — это справочник Розенталя, § 53:

> 5. <...> Если слушатель перебивает рассказчика, то разговор, происходивший ранее, дается с абзацев и в кавычках, чтобы не
>    смешивались фразы рассказчика и слушателя с диалогом, приводимым
>    рассказчиком:
>
> *...Путешественник начал свой рассказ:*
>
> *— Это было в самый разгар нашего похода. Подошёл ко мне проводник и
> говорит: «Придётся на некоторое время задержаться». «Почему? Что-нибудь
> случилось?»*
>
> *— А действительно что-нибудь случилось? — не выдержал один из
> слушавших путешественника.*
>
> *— Сейчас скажу.*

Comment: Обращения через @ работают для тех, кто уже комментировал.

Comment: Да? Не знал... Вроде где-то недавно был вопрос, в котором автор приглашал к дискуссии (через @) ряд пользователей, не прокомментировавших ещё вопрос.

Comment: Проверим ещё раз. Они иногда вносят изменения в систему. Написал вам два сообщения с @ под левым ответом и вопросом. Пришло? Нельзя уведомить более одного участника, система не принимает такой комментарий.

Comment: Неа, не пришло. Значит, я что-то не так углядел в тот раз.

Answer (score 2):

О [первом](https://books.google.ee/books?id=5EQwEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT125&lpg=PT125&dq=%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C:%20%C2%AB%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC?%C2%BB%20%C2%AB%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA,%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E,%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA.&source=bl&ots=JkJscsb41P&sig=ACfU3U2o_fz5xU9Ak0IQ7QKh60szbWTeuQ&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU9Yi0pcX1AhUSt4sKHdDDB2MQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q=%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%3A%20%C2%AB%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%3F%C2%BB%20%C2%AB%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%2C%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E%2C%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA.&f=false) примере (П. Сафоненков. Григорий Гладков: грустный Клоун с гитарой)

Дело в том, что предложение про Ленина со словом "говорю" оформлено в книге не как [***реплика***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) (ответ, возражение, замечание одного собеседника на слова другого), а как полноценная прямая речь со словами автора внутри: **«П, — а, — П»**. Поэтому тут и не нужно никакого тире.

Считаю, что это предложение написано с ошибкой: "говорю" здесь является вводным словом и должно быть выделено одиночными запятыми. Вот в этом случае, думаю, можно использовать тире:
*Тут они напряглись: «Это что еще за мультфильм?» — «Ну как, **говорю,** Ленин был очень веселый человек. Сделаю смешное кино про Ленина — все обхохочутся».*

О [втором](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=67172&p=58) примере

> **2.** Если реплики следуют **в подбор**, без указания, кому они принадлежат, то каждая из них заключается **в кавычки** и отделяется от соседней **тире**:
> *«Так ты женат? Не знал я ране! Давно ли?» — «Около двух лет». — «На ком?» — «На Лариной». — «Татьяне?» — «Ты ей знаком?» — «Я им сосед»* (П.).
> **3.** Если после реплики идут слова автора, то перед следующей репликой тире опускается:
> *«Не видать?» — повторил барин. «Не видать», — вторично ответствовал слуга* (Т.)...

Здесь можно сказать то же самое. Нет в этом отрывке "чистых" реплик, а имеются подряд три предложения с прямой речью: два — со словами автора внутри (не реплики), третье — со словами автора после прямой речи (можно посчитать репликой).
Такие конструкции оформляются как обычные предложения со своими знаками препинания, тире между ними не ставится.

[Знаки препинания при прямой речи](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=154#pp154) (Розенталь)

Comment: У Розенталя не рассмотрен следующий случай (немного изменю его пример): "Барин повторил: «Не видать?» «Не видать», — вторично ответствовал слуга". — вот в таком случае нужно ли тире между репликами? К тому же я не понял разделение на реплики и не-реплики. Я всегда полагал, что реплика — это высказывание одного персонажа в диалоге, и она может снабжаться авторскими словами, а может не снабжаться.  По-видимому, я неправ?

Comment: И ещё насчёт второго примера: если третье предложение мы сочтём репликой, а первые два — нет, то получается, что перед последним-то предложением должно стоять тире?
*"«Послушай, — сказал он как можно проникновеннее... — послушай, дело в самой моей истории. В ней все не так, как кажется. Во-первых, я не собирался спасать никакого ребенка, я просто почувствовал, что вот сейчас смогу прыгнуть». «Конечно, ты мог прыгнуть! — нетерпеливо перебила Кира. — Ты был спортсмен, кандидат в мастера!» — «Как-нибудь потом объясню», — смутился Ведерников"*. Но ведь это выглядит нелепо.

Comment: @Nektoid Не-не... Во втором примере не нужно тире. Вот классика: "Скажи-ка мне, красавица, — спросил я, — что ты делала сегодня на кровле?" — "А смотрела, откуда ветер дует". — "Зачем тебе?" — "Откуда ветер, оттуда и счастье". — "Что же, разве ты песнею зазывала счастье?" — "Где поется, там и счастливится" (М. Лермонтов. Герой нашего времени).

Comment: Римма, замучился я уже :). Я бы везде (со словами автора или без, реплика / не реплика) между кавычками ставил тире:  ...». – «...  Реплика ведь необязательно должна быть короткой. Это как раз касается второго примера, где всё можно считать репликами (ответами, возражениями, краткими выступлениями и пр.). И подходит под правило Лопатина с: *Проходя мимо, он крикнул: «Не унывай!» — «Постараюсь», — ответила я*.

Comment: Вот так, **без** слов автора **внутри** первых двух предложений, **можно** оформить с тире: «Послушай... послушай, дело в самой моей истории. В ней все не так, как кажется. Во-первых, я не собирался спасать никакого ребенка, я просто почувствовал, что вот сейчас смогу прыгнуть». — «Конечно, ты мог прыгнуть! Ты был спортсмен, кандидат в мастера!» — «Как-нибудь потом объясню», — смутился Ведерников.

Comment: Я и говорю, что недоработано в правилах. Про ***внутри*** не сказано, зато есть это: "...точка и тире ставятся между репликами, принадлежащими разным лицам и снабженными разными авторскими словами".